# How do I check the data structure of this imported data in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through a tutorial and see the following import statement:

```
import pet, { ANIMALS } from "@frontendmasters/pet";
```

This is the [Pet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@frontendmasters/pet) API

I want to look at the structure of the data that I'm importing so tried:

```
console.log(ANIMALS)

console.log(pets)
```

but this is showing as "not defined"

How should I `console.log` this to see the data structure? (Object/Array etc)

Comment: Where have you called the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://npm.runkit.com/%40frontendmasters%2Fpet

I ran this test:

```
var pet = require("@frontendmasters/pet")

console.log(pet)
```

the output is:

```
 Object {ANIMALS: ["barnyard", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse", "rabbit", 
 "scales-fins-other", "small-furry"], …}
```

I also noticed you are using React go here bottom right click on console to see output:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-forest-olu2g

this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import pet from "@frontendmasters/pet";

export default function App() {
  console.log(pet);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You may have to click on the refresh button within the sandbox browser to see the results.